# GDM session list borked

Tags: 11.04, unity, gdm

I must have done something especially stupid, but I observe the following behavior:

1. When I start gdm, I see the "Warning: unable to load /etc/gdm/custom.conf: file not found" message.
2. My GDM session list contains only to basic sessions (an empty one and an xterm one) available in /usr/share/xsessions.

My question is: what exactly have I broken and how do I bring Unity xsession config back? If it's as simple as copying a file into /usr/share/xsessions, I'd be grateful if someone posted a working unity config here, since when I launch Unity from xterm with simply `unity`, none of my settings are applied. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try reinstalling the `gnome-session` package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session
```