# gdm only starts an xterm; how to get back my desktop?

Tags: 10.04, xorg, startup, gdm, autostart

On my Intel integrated graphics touchscreen with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, after an `apt-get upgrade` from 10.04.1 LTS to 10.04.4 LTS, `sudo less /var/log/gdm/:0-slave.log` shows 3 lines, the first being: `gdm-session-worker[1040]: GLIB-GObject-CRITICAL: g_value_get_boolean: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_BOOLEAN (value)' failed`.

I rebooted and still ended up at a blank black screen with an undecorated white terminal window in the upper left corner. Ctrl+Alt+F1 to login at a text console and `sudo ps x |grep gdm` show gdm-binary, gdm-simple-slave, and X auth gdm aotaIM or something, and gdm-session-worker running.

`sudo service gdm restart` merely restarts the same X session. How do i get my Gnome taskbar etc. back?

`sudo service gdm stop && startx` almost works (my taskbar doesn't appear when i press Alt+F1), but how should i fix it properly?

```
xterm$ gdmsetup
xterm$ cat /etc/gdm/custom.conf
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=b
TimedLoginEnable=true
TimedLogin=b
TimedLoginDelay=10
xterm$ sudo nano /etc/gdm/custom.conf
xterm$ cat /etc/gdm/custom.conf
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=b
TimedLoginEnable=true
TimedLogin=b
TimedLoginDelay=10
DefaultSession=gnome
xterm$ sudo reboot
```

No difference. **gdmsetup still won't unlock.** When ran with sudo, the unlock button greys out but i still can't change the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it thanks to https://askubuntu.com/a/42954/42522

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session`

Apparently removing Evolution before the upgrade also removed some critical components.