# GNOME/GDM not starting

Tags: gnome, apt, 10.04, pulseaudio, gdm

**NOTE: While working through my issue and documenting it I discovered the solution, but have decided to post this in case another person has the same/similar issue (see bottom)...**

After uninstalling the PulseAudio Equalizer and rebooting, I have lost my desktop (GNOME).

Upon powering up the Ubuntu start-up screen displays... then a generic login screen appears, and after logging in, I only get a terminal window... see: http://www.locusplex.us/images/screenshots.jpg

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Lucid on a Dell Latitude 13.

I have tried:

```
~$ sudo startx
```

which returns:

```
Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
If the server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock and start again
```

removing the file:

```
~$ sudo rm /tmp/.X0-lock
```

and trying ('startx') again yields:

```
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeA11COTSServerListenerrs: server already running
Fatal server error:
Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure the X Server isn't already running
```

After stopping/starting the X Server:

```
~$ sudo stop gdm
~$ gdm stop/waiting
~$ sudo start gdm
```

I am taken back to the login screen like before (see image above).

Stopping the server again ('sudo stop gdm') then trying:

```
~$ sudo startx
```

again yields:

```
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeA11COTSServerListenerrs: server already running
Fatal server error:
Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure the X Server isn't already running
```

I have searched multiple forums, including Ask Ubuntu and found a few related threads:

[GDM Killed at Startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77652/gdm-killed-on-startup)
I have attempted the suggestions there with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f -m --reinstall -u gdm
```

The log reports:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
Do you want to continue [Y/n] Y
```

A bit more logging and end with:

```
Setting up gdm (2.30.2 is.2.30.0-0ubuntu5.2 ...
```

Next per the suggestion:

```
~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
~$ sudo reboot
```

Then I find myself back at the previously described login screen.

Comment: Please, instead of putting the solution inside of the question, post an actual answer (and accept it).

Answer (score 7):

SOLUTION/FIX that worked for me: From Ask Ubuntu, [GDM session list borked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42950/gdm-session-list-borked/42954#42954)

```
Try reinstalling the gnome-session package:
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session
```

Comment: Just upgraded to buster and was in the same boat: greeter worked, logged in to nothing but a blue screen. This solved the problem, thanks!